# load balance algorithm in digitalocean

Tags: load-balancing, digital-ocean

I use the load balance feature in digitalocean as shown below, can the load balance algorithm be changed?

Picture here

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Not any more

There used to be an algorithm drop down to switch between round robin and least connections but it is not there anymore